# Extract words from string based on spaces and parenthesis

Tags: regex, go, split

I have some strings that correspond to words separated by spaces and that can be grouped using parenthesis. I also have an array of strings that represent the groups present in the string (not necessarily in the same order).

Here is an example :

```
myString = "zzz AND (aaa AND (bbb AND ccc OR ddd) ) OR eee AND \"fff  fff\" AND (ggg)"
myGroups = ["(ggg)", "(aaa AND (bbb AND ccc OR ddd) )"]
```

I want to split that query on spaces that are not inside quotes and that are not inside parenthesis. The output of the split on the previous string would be as follow :

```
["zzz", "AND", "(aaa AND (bbb AND ccc OR ddd) )", "OR", "eee", "AND", "\"fff  fff\"", "AND", "(ggg)"]
```

I succeeded to split on spaces that are not inside quotes using the regex

```
\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)
```

But I am struggling with adding the notion of groups in this.

Note :

- `myString` may contain nested groups, but I only want to split on the outer one
- No need to handle cases where parenthesis syntax is wrong

Comment: What environment are you implementing this in?

Comment: I am doing this with Golang, but any kind of solution would be ok, I can adapt :)

Comment: Your `mString` input has unescaped double quotes, and I doubt would even compile (in any language).  That aside, you are dealing with nested content, and probably should be using a parser, not regex.

Comment: You are right, I edited the string.
I will look how I can do without regex then, thanks

Comment: In a single pass on the string you can generate the result,
you need a list to save the words processed,
one buffer to add characters until you reach a space
and 2 counters that you increment/decrement when you reach a `(` or `)` and for the second one with `"`, `"`. You treat spaces as real separator only when both counters are at zero, if they are not at zero, space should be considered as normal letters and should be appended to the buffer of char, until you reach a separator at this point you reset the buffer and add the word to the list of saved words.

Comment: I was working on it but you are faster than me. Thank you !

Comment: Your regex won't work in Go since its regexp does not support lookarounds. You can't solve it with a single regex. Use Allan's logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
// PHP 
$re = '/(\((([^()]*|(?1))*)\))|(\\\\"[^\\\\]+\\\\"|[^\s]+)/m';
$str = 'zzz AND (aaa AND (bbb AND ccc OR ddd) ) OR eee AND \\"fff  fff\\" AND (ggg)';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$result = array_column($matches, 0);
print_r($result);

// output
Array
(
    [0] => zzz
    [1] => AND
    [2] => (aaa AND (bbb AND ccc OR ddd) )
    [3] => OR
    [4] => eee
    [5] => AND
    [6] => \"fff  fff\"
    [7] => AND
    [8] => (ggg)
)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VowQbk/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
([\w]*)*?(?:(\([\w ]+(?2)*\))(?2)*)*?(\"[\w ]+\")?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFZiIi/1)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hi, I did't understand what you say. Can you write a little simpler? My English is not very well.